# Comments not Getting Inserted into MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use the code below for a comment system.  It doesn't work.  The info I'm trying to insert into the MySQL table "comment" isn't getting put there.  Any idea(s) why it is not working?

Thanks in advance,

John

On comments.php:

```
echo '<form action="http://www...com/sandbox/comments/comments2.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['loginid'].'" name="uid">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submissionid.'" name="submissionid">  

    <label class="addacomment" for="title">Add a comment:</label>
    <input class="commentsubfield" name="comment" type="title" id="comment" maxlength="1000">  

    <div class="commentsubbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
</form>
';
```

On comments2.php:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$subid = $_POST['submissionid'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$subid', '$comment', NULL, NULL)");
```

Comment: Does it know what database to connect to? Does it know what schema to talk to? Have you connected to the database? mysql_connect() Have you selected the database? mysql_select_db()

Comment: You have zero error handling. At the top of your receiving script, use `var_dump($_POST)` to ensure the post data is coming across. Right after your call to `mysql_query`, make a call to `mysql_error()` to check any error messages that might be missed. It's also always A Good Idea to store the SQL statement in a var for future reference, ensure the statement you *think* is being sent is actually being sent.

Comment: Since no one has explicitly mentioned it yet, the problem is in your SQL string that you're passing to the mysql_query() function.  You haven't correctly concatenated the $variables; you're actually inserting the variable names as values.   You need to use the . string concat operator, as you've correctly done above when echoing out the form values from your Session.  Think '".$uid."' etc.  Or use the nifty sprintf() function mentioned below.  HTH.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO comment VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s', '%s', NULL, NULL)", $uid, $subid, $comment);

mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

If [mysql_query()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_query) fails it returns `false` and [mysql_error()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_error) can tell you why.
Also take a look at http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection and either use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or prepared statements.

```
if ( !isset($_POST['comment'], $_POST['uid'], $_POST['submissionid']) ) {
  echo '<pre>Debug: Something is missing. _POST=',
    htmlspecialchars( print_r($_POST, 1) ),
    '</pre>';
  die;
}
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'], $mysql);
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uid'], $mysql);
$subid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submissionid'], $mysql);

$query = "
  INSERT INTO
    comment
  VALUES
    (NULL, '$uid', '$subid', '$comment', NULL, NULL)
";
echo '<pre>Debug query=', htmlspecialchars($query), '</pre>';
$rc=mysql_query($query, $mysql);
if ( !$rc ) {
  die( htmlspecialchars(mysql_error()) );
}
```

Try this self-contained example (only an example, don't code it this way ;-))

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset($_SESSION['loginid']) ) {
  login();
}
else if ( !isset($_POST['comment']) ) {
  showForm();
}
else {
  saveComment();
}

function saveComment() {
   if ( !isset($_POST['comment'], $_POST['uid'], $_POST['submissionid']) ) {
    echo '<pre>Debug: Something is missing. _POST=',
      htmlspecialchars( print_r($_POST, 1) ),
      '</pre>';
    die;
  }
  // insert correct values here:
  $mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('test', $mysql) or die(mysql_error());

  $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'], $mysql);
  $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uid'], $mysql);
  $subid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submissionid'], $mysql);

  $query = "
    INSERT INTO
      comment
    VALUES
      (NULL, '$uid', '$subid', '$comment', NULL, NULL)
  ";
  echo '<pre>Debug query=', htmlspecialchars($query), '</pre>';
  //$rc=mysql_query($query, $mysql);
  //if ( !$rc ) {
    //die( htmlspecialchars(mysql_error()) );
  //}
}


function login() {
  $_SESSION['loginid'] = rand(1, 100);
  echo 'Your new loginid is ', $_SESSION['loginid'],'<br />
    <a href="?">Continue</a>
  ';
}

function showForm() {
  $submissionid = rand(1000, 9999);
  echo '<div>submissionid=', $submissionid, '</div>';
  echo '<div>loginid=', $_SESSION['loginid'], '</div>';

  echo '<form action="?" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['loginid'].'" name="uid">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submissionid.'" name="submissionid">  

    <label class="addacomment" for="title">Add a comment:</label>
    <input class="commentsubfield" name="comment" type="title" id="comment" maxlength="1000">  

    <div class="commentsubbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
  </form>
  ';
}
```

if this "works" compare it to your real application and find the (essential) differences.

Comment: I tried this, and it returned <pre>Debug query=
  INSERT INTO
    comment
  VALUES
    (NULL, '', '', '', NULL, NULL)
</pre>

Doe this mean that the query is not getting the variables?

Comment: Certainly looks that way. Code updated. btw: You've copied the <pre> element from the output as well. Did you get this from your browser's source view or are you running this script from the command line (cli)?

Comment: I ran the update version of your code, and got <pre>Debug: Something is missing. _POST=Array
(
)
</pre>  Does this mean that I am doing the POST wrongly?

Comment: The <pre> is from the source code; I guess I don't need to copy it.

Comment: self-contained example added. - Is there a reason why you transmit the loginid in an input/hidden instead of using _SESSION['loginid'] in comment2.php ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your self-contained example... and I don't have a reason for not using the Session variable in comment2.php

Comment: The only "important" function in the example is saveComment(). Everything else is just a dummy setup to provide the data/environment for that function. Just put the script in one file, put in your mysql credentials/database name  and call it from the browser (I promise as long as you keep the mysql\_query() code in comments there's nothing harmful in that script ;-)) The only point of the script is to show that it _can_ be done and that -__if__ it works- something (essential) must be different in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

### Valid return values from yourform

Does

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$subid = $_POST['submissionid'];
```

contain valid data?

### SQL query valid

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

### What does mysql_query return

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

what mysql_error do you get for your query.

### Use PDO instead of mysql_query()

I would advise you to have a look at [PDO](http://ezinearticles.com/?SQL-Injection-Protection-in-PHP-With-PDO&id=1815110) which does a lot of heavy lifting for you. It for example makes sure that your SQL query is safe because even if the comments was added to your database it could(would) not be safe at all.

### PHP security

You should always validate your users input to prevent [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Luckily when using PDO(using prepared statements which will also give you a speed boost)right this will be done for you behind the seens. Still I would advise you to read these quick [security](http://talks.php.net/show/flux) tips from PHP creator to secure your site.

---

Hopefully this tips will help you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You need the field names for any INSERT statement. As I don't know the exact ones for your table, I'll make some guesses.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment(uid,subid,comment) VALUES($uid, $subid, $comment)");
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think you do, if you're adding all table fields (exclusive of the identity column, etc.)  At least it's that way in other database realms; will double-check for MySQL.

Comment: If you don't specify the field names it inserts a whole row, which is what he is handling with those 3 `NULL`s

Comment: No, no, no. You *should* use field names to explicitly target certain fields, but as long as your data matches the number of fields in the table you can omit them. Thus the NULL values.